# Cannot type the @ symbol on Spanish keyboard?

Tags: keyboard-layout

I've recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and cannot print the @ symbol. I mean get the symbol shown in the screen, when I type an email in the browser, into a document, etc.

My keyboard is set in spanish.

I've tried Alt + 64 -using the numeric keyboard- and nothing happens.

I've tried creating a shortcut, (setting it as: Alt+64), and is set as "disabled"...

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spanish keyboard layout has the @ sign on the number 2 key. Press AltGr, keep it pressed, press 2.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Number</kbd> only works in Windows systems. To print the @ character you should be able in a Spanish keyboard with:

- <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>
- <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>

With any keyboard:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> you will get a underlined u, type `0040` and press enter or space.

In an english keyboard:

- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>